# C^0 and C^1 small deformation of identity

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am trying to figure out what does it mean to be $C^0$ and $C^1$ small for a diffeomorphism f. Because of the term "small" I believe they are induced from a norm, but I couldn't think of what might that be for a noncompact manifold. When I check from Munkres, there are compact open and uniform topologies on function spaces. But there is no mention to topology on function spaces induced from a norm. Are these topologies related to what I am looking for?